Computation of an expectation with Khi 2
Suppose I have a random value $X$ that follows a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ law. Is it possible to compute those two expectations :
$$\operatorname{E} \left[ \frac{1}{1 - X^2} \right] $$
and :
$$\operatorname{E} \left[ \frac{1}{-1 + X^2}\right] $$
?
I think those two expectations are finite. I would like to use a power serie expansion for :
$$ \frac{1}{1 - X^2} $$ and $$\frac{1}{-1 + X^2} $$
But I do not find a closed formula. Thanks in advance.

What would you guess the associated integrals would be for these expectations?

A series expansion for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is $\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } x^{2 i}$ and that says that the expectation is not finite.

Tnanks you.  I thought the integral was : $$ \operatorname{E} \left[  \frac{1}{-1 + X^2}\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})}{-1 + x^2} dx$$ And I thought this integral was finite
